# How to host a Mosquitto MQTT broker on EC2 so that i can use it with Eclipse Paho?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, mosquitto

I have installed mosquitto MQTT broker on Amazon EC2 windows server.
How can I publish and subscribe messages from Eclipse Paho which is installed in another computer?

Mainly what to write in place of localhost in Eclipse Paho?

I have also configured security groups for HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, MQTT (custom TCP port 8000,1883,8883).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the public IP address of your EC2 instance instead of localhost.

Details on finding the IP addresses of your EC2 instance can be found here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html